# Docker push image to repository

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-registry, to-be-continuous

When using "to be continuous" [Docker template](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/docker), the Docker image is built and pushed to `DOCKER_SNAPSHOT_IMAGE` or `DOCKER_RELEASE_IMAGE`.

Why is there a step to publish image with skopeo, if that is already done in the built step ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Docker template uses 2 images is [explained in the documentation](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/docker#images).

Basically the Docker image is first built and published as the **snapshot** image (`DOCKER_SNAPSHOT_IMAGE`). This is done in the `package-build` stage.

Once the image has been validated (by deploying and/or testing it thoroughly), the **same image** is promoted as the **release** image. This doesn't involve rebuilding it, just pushing it as another Docker image (`DOCKER_RELEASE_IMAGE`). For this we use [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo). This is done in the `publish` stage, that necessarily comes after `package-test`, `deploy` and `acceptance`.